# Map pin image is not changing

Tags: ios, swift

i try to change pin image on did select but default image is still presenting on screen under the new image. since an image for selected state - the default image is still visible outside new image.

if i set `view.image = nil` - the default image is still presenting.

tested on simulator and real device

> ```
> override func viewDidLoad(){
>    super.viewDidLoad()
>    mapView.delegate = self
> }
> ```

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let pin = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
       pin.image = UIImage(named: "PinDefault")
       pin.canShowCallout = false
       return pin
   } 

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
       view.image = UIImage(named: "PinSelected")
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
       view.image = UIImage(named: "PinDefault")
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have declared your map view's delegate to self?

Comment: sure. in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code, to customize pin in MapKit.

first, I'm creating a custom class to have full access to annotation.

```
class AnnotationMapKit: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var overlayRadius: Double?
var identifire = "pin"
var leftDetail: UIView?
var rightDetail: UIView?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
     title: String?,
     subtitle: String? = nil,
     leftDetail: UIView? = nil,
     rightDetail: UIView? = nil,
     overlayRadius: Double? = nil) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.leftDetail = leftDetail
    self.rightDetail = rightDetail
    self.overlayRadius = overlayRadius
}
```

}

then in my controller:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView()
    guard let annotation = annotation as? AnnotationMapKit else { return nil}
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotation.identifire) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        annotationView = dequedView
    } else {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.identifire)
    }

    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "ir")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true // by default it's turned off, so nothing will show at the annotations.

    let paragraph = UILabel()
    paragraph.numberOfLines = 0
    paragraph.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
    paragraph.textColor = .red
    paragraph.text = annotation.title

    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = annotation.leftDetail
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = annotation.rightDetail
    annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = paragraph

    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
           return nil
        }

       let annotationIdentifier = "Identifier"
       var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

       if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier:annotationIdentifier) {
       annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
       annotationView?.annotation = annotation
       }
     else
       {
       annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
       annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
       }

       if let annotationView = annotationView {

       annotationView.canShowCallout = true
       annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImagename”)
    }
  return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Declare this on your class level:

```
let pin = MKAnnotationView?
```

& then:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
   pin = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
   pin.image = UIImage(named: "PinDefault")
   pin.canShowCallout = false
   return pin
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   pin.image = UIImage(named: "PinSelected")
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   pin.image = UIImage(named: "PinDefault")
}
```